# Using Microsoft Power Automate - Include a link in an email to document(s) in a SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have the following list and document library in the same SharePoint site:

`SharePoint List` (Policy Inventory):

[image: Sharepoint List]

`SharePoint Document Library` (Policy-Working-Documents):
[image: Sharepoint Document Library]

My current flow filters for items in the list with a `review date` that is +120 days from today, then it gets the files from the document library sub-folder named `Test-Folder`.

I am really struggling with the following:

1. Filtering the `Get Files` output so as to keep only the files with a `Name` that is also contained in the output of `Get Items`?
2. Send an `Outlook` email that contains the documents from #1 as an attachment or link. The body of the email should include the `Document Name` and `Review Date` which are provided in the `Policy Inventory` list.

My current flow:

[image]

**Troubleshooting**

Current Flow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
**Note that `ReviewDocs` `Body` is available in the `Dynamic Content` for the `Apply to each - ReviewItem`, but I selected the `Body` from `PolicyReview120` as instructed. After doing this, I am unable to select the `Body` from `ReviewDocs` in the `From` field in the `Filter array`**

Comment: How does Policy-Inventory list link to the Policy-Working-Document?  If they are not link, how do you envision linking them? A) you get the list items B) Now you need to get the files from the library based on the list items. Yes, once you get the files, you can attach to an email. Please provide some sample data to understand this.

Comment: @MatiurRahman I have added screenshots of my List and Document Library. I was thinking of somehow using `Apply to each` with a `condition` to see if the `Name` in the document library is contained in the `Get Items` output then send an email and within the email attach the document. Please note, the list and document library are much larger outside of this sample.

Comment: Sure.. I will take look into it little later today. You might already know that there's a limitation as to how many items you can retrieve from the list/library and process in the Flow with Apply to each loop. Regardless, best option is to filter the data in the SharePoint first. Do you think you can filter using [Created] date so that not to bring a whole lot of old records into the Flow?

Comment: I don't see any space at the beginning or at the end of string {Name} and {DocumentName}. However, there is space within the string. Not sure whether it is a single or multiple spaces. Can you click on the "Edit in advance mode" under [Filter array] and hard code value such as "test 120 day" on the both side of the [is equal to]  as the filter  in the condition and try again. Just don't use the dynamic content and see if the Filter array is working. Also, you can troubleshoot by creating a new list item/uploading a new doc without any "spaces" in the DocumentName/Name.

Comment: Also, you may check whether the correct dynamic properties been selected under [Filter array]. 1) Body should be the JSON object from Policy-Working-Documents, that is, Output of the [ReviewDocs] action. And filter query should match as I described in my response. But let's confirm whether hard-coded value is working or not and then we'll focus on the dynamic content.

Comment: I hardcoded as instructed and the `Filter array` worked giving a proper output. The `From` in the `Filter array` is only displaying `value` for `ReviewDocs` in the `Dynamic content`. `PolicyReview120` is showing `Body` as an option. Not sure why `Body` isn't also showing for `ReviewDocs`. I have included a screenshot showing this at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: For [Filter array], you can use **value** from the dynamic content to filter ReviewDocs. Try using that to see what you get. I'm not sure why "Body" is not available. Maybe you can close and reopen the Flow to see if there anything to do with the cache. The main thing I'm noticing in the output of Filter array is that it showing **Input** values from PolicyReview120, not from ReviewDocs. You should see "{Name}" in the Input parameter.

Comment: I mean, in the Filter array output after running the flow, the  INPUTS **From** should show  values like: **"{Name}": "test 120 day",
    "{FilenameWithExtension}": "test 120 day 3.docx",**. But your screenshot is showing values (DocumentName) from PolicyReview120. That means, Filter array input is not correct

Comment: I think my schema could be causing an error. For both `PolicyReview120` and `ReviewDocs` the schema shows `"type": "object"`. Should the Schema `type` be an `array`? Perhaps seeing the details of the steps you took to Parse `'Get items` and `Get files` could help me ensure I did those steps correctly. BTW thank you so much again for helping me. I have learned SO much already.

Comment: Here is link to a GIF of my flow. 

[GIF of my Flow via Imgur](https://imgur.com/gallery/1QWoqBk)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113984/discussion-between-iamericfletcher-and-matiur-rahman).

Comment: My schema starts with **{   "type": "array". **.  You need to take the entire output from [Compose] action as a sample to feed into [Parse JSON] to generate schema. Do you have more than one item in the [Get Items]? If not, add couple of more so that you have more than one items returned in the query. The output of the [Compose] should start with a "[" indicating an array. I will catch you on chat later today. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are the steps that can be used to fulfil the requirements**:

1. Get [**Policy Inventory**] Items with a Filter Query, as currently you're doing
2. Create JSON object from the output from step 1
3. Get all Documents' Properties from [**Policy-Working-Documents**]/Test-Folder. Filter Query can be applied if a meta data field is available in the library
4. Create Document property JSON object collection from the output from step 3
5. Loop through all the list items in the collection in step 2
6. While looping through, **Filter** the Review Docs collection in step 4
7. Add [Select] action to **Select** properties to be included in the email
8. Add [Apply to each] after [Select] and construct an email to send.

**Please see the screenshots showing the Flow Steps**

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 1.1

[image]

**Sample of email sent**- can be further customized

[image]

**List and Library data used to TEST**
[image]

[image]

**Further Enhancement**

The document under review can be attached to the email by retrieving the content
of the file by adding [*Get file content*] before sending emails. This requires [File Identifier] which is already included in the [Get Files (properties] action
output. This Property need to be added to the [Select] action and then can be used in the [Apply to each] action below it.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response. I will try and implement your solution later tonight.

Comment: It took a while for me to do it. But it worked for me. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I think I have it right up until `Send an email (V2)`. In the body of the email, the Dynamic content is not showing the items from the above `Select` map (DocumentLink, ReviewDate, not DocName)... Any ideas? My `Filter array` in the `Apply to each - ReviewItem` shows `Outputs` as [] -- there is nothing in the body. It is blank. That is probably the problem? The `Filter Array` is made of of:

From = the `Body` from PolicyReview120

`string(item()['{Name}'])` on the left

is equal to

`string(items('Apply_to_each_-_ReviewItem')['DocumentName'])` on the right

Comment: Before checking values in the Send Email, can you compare output from action PolicyReview120, property [DocumentName], with Property [Name] from ReviewDocs? If they look matching, you can use trim() and toUpper() functions in the Filter array, like toUpper(trim(string(item()['{Name}']))) =toUpper(trim(string(items('Apply_to_each_-_ReviewItem')['DocumentName'])))

Comment: Hmmm. They matched so I edited the `Filter array` to include `toUpper` for both and still getting no output. I have attached screenshots to my original post under `Troubleshooting` at the bottom if you have time to take a look at them.

Comment: Hey! Apparently things have worked out. I seemed to have gotten it to work! I learned so much and cannot thank you enough for taking the time to help me, a newbie to Power Automate! Thank you Thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked out for you now! Again, let me know if you have any further questions.